# Can I build a 4A circuit on cardboard?

Tags: circuit-design, temperature, heat, board, stripboard

I'm planning to build a 12V 4A circuit, and I was originally going to put it on a strip board. However, the board I ordered came broken (and each piece would be a bit small for building a circuit), and I don't have time to order a new one. Additionally, I'm starting to realize that my circuit setup would be pretty difficult to set up keeping the strips in mind, and I would need to widen some of the holes to fit certain components. Since I have a decent amount of a 16 guage wire to link the components without a board, would it work to stick everything on a sheet of cardboard? Do I have to worry about the cardboard catching fire at a high wattage due to heat from the leads?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it would work and yes you might have to consider the possibility of the cardboard lighting up under high loads. If you do it right you might be fine. Maybe consider building a boardless circuit. Look up "flywire circuits" and you will see examples. If you use heavy solid wire for you ground you could even incorporate mounting loops in the wire. It will take a little more skill but your results can be beautiful,  last for years and be fireproof.

Answer (score 0):

if the leads are thick enough to not overheat then cardboard can work. at-least temporarily, if it gets folded there could be a short-circuit.

FR2 which stripboard is usually made from is cardboard that has a fire-retardant resin soaked into it which also adds stiffness.

Comment: Some of the components don't look like they have extremely thick leads (such as this resistor: https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/652-PWR221T-50-6R00F). Is there any way I can find out how much the leads will heat up?

Comment: on most resistors only the body heats up because the current is small because it's a resistor

Comment: one option is to put staples in the cardboard and use them for anchor points only, and not put ant coductors through the cardboard - support everything of wires soldered to the staples.

Comment: I'm using two 6 ohm resistors in parallel, so each should have 2A running through it.

Comment: yeah the resistor leads will be hot from heat made in the body of the resistor, but 2A won;'t make a resistor lead self-heat much

Comment: Ok, I am planning to attach a heatsink to the resistor, so that could help the body heating situation. The circuit will also be on for only a few seconds at a time, although I imagine the heat capacity of cardboard is pretty low. As for the stapling idea, would there still be conductors on top of the cardboard, where things are soldered together? Won't the solder being spread out on the cardboard make things worse?

Answer (score 0):

The alternative would be to use lug strips, mounted on an aluminium sheet/chassis, to interconnect the components (point-to-point wiring). The aluminium sheet/chassis may also serve as a heatsink if necessary.